# Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncommand the line no: 2 in Ios/Podfile.
Like this platform :ios, ’10.0. and run application

[see refer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVOEW.png)

Answer (score 3):

1. iOS -> Podfile -> change
   platform :ios, ’10.0’ to platform :ios, '12.0'
2. Run command “flutter clean”
3. Run command “flutter build iOS”
4. Run command “cd iOS”
5. Run command “pod update”
6. Run command “pod install”
7. Run command “flutter run”